# Even and odd functions in Laurent decomposition

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have the following problem and have no idea how to approach it, could anyone give me any hint about it? Thanks!

Suppose that $f(z) = f_0(z) + f_1(z)$ is the Laurent decomposition of an analytic function $f(z)$ on the annulus $\{A < |z| < B \}$. Show that if $f(z) $ is an even function, then $f_0(z)$ and $f_1(z)$ are even functions.

Answer (score 2):

$$
 f_0(-z) + f_1(-z) = f(-z) = f(z) = f_0(z) + f_1(z)
$$
in $\{A < |z| < B \}$, and the Laurent decomposition 
(with the normalization $\lim_{z \to \infty} f_1(z) = 0$)
is *unique*:

Define $h : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C $  by
$$
 h(z) = \begin{cases}
   f_0(-z) - f_0(z) & \text{ for } |z| < B \\
   f_1(z) - f_1(-z) & \text{ for } |z| > A \\
\end{cases}
$$
and verify that

- $h$ is well-defined,
- $h$ is an entire function, and finally,
- $h$ is identically zero.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with Martin R's answer, we have that $\lim_{z \to \infty} f_1(z) = 0$, so $f_1$ is bounded.

Also, since $f_0$ is analytic, and hence continuous, on the compact set $|z| < B$, $f_0$ is bounded. Therefore, $h(z)$ is bounded and analytic on the entire plane. Liouville's theorem implies that $h(z)$ is identically zero.

Therefore, both $f_0$ and $f_1$ are even.